# how to manually insert value in textbox which not replace automatically in slider extension

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are using Slider Extender control when we are manually insert into textbox which is boundControlID of that slider Extender control
The slider min value is 1 and max value is 50 if I change manually into boundcontrolID textbox “ 25 “ the slider move to 25 but when I insert 55 it will move 50 and in textbox 55 replace by 50 automatically, but I want that 55 should not be replaced.

Here is some code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Size" CssClass="FormLabel"></asp:Label></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <cc1:SliderExtender 
                    ID="SliderExtender1"
                    runat="server"
                    TargetControlID="TextBox1"
                    BoundControlID="TextBox2"                                  
                    Minimum="1"
                    Maximum="50"
                    >
                </cc1:SliderExtender> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox" OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Sorry You Enter Size is above 50 TB" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" Font-Names="Segoe UI"></asp:Label></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>        
        </div>
      </div>
```

C# code :

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text;
            SliderExtender1.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: DId you try removing max value, as you dont want the max value to be persisted on view ?

Comment: no we are not try to removing max value coz we are using this control first time that's why don't know about it